# How to insert a second multirow after one in an earlier column?

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to add second multirow after the first in a later column of a row. The problem is that the text in that column is not centred as shown in the image below. Additionally, there is only one vertical line closing each row of the table.

[image]

Here is the latex code I am using:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | }
    \hline
    Scene & Type & Time (ms) & Difference  \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & Type A & \SI{10}{ms} \\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{ms} & \multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{ms}} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{B} & Type A & \SI{10}{ms} \\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{ms} & \multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{ms}} \\ \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{C} & Type A & \SI{10}{ms} \\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{ms} & \multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{ms}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

How would you centre the text in the 'Difference (ms)' column like it is in the 'Scene' column? And fix the missing lines?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | }
    \hline
    Scene & Type & Time (ms) & Difference  \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & Type A & \SI{10}{\milli\second} & \multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{\milli\second}}\\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{\milli\second} &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{B} & Type A & \SI{10}{\milli\second} & \multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{\milli\second}}\\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{\milli\second} &  \\ \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{C} & Type A & \SI{10}{\milli\second} &\multirow{2}{*}{\SI{0}{\milli\second}}  \\
     & Type B & \SI{10}{\milli\second} & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]